# tkinter send text from the label to entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I send send text from the label to entry box, or send directly the path of the image to entry box in `tkinter`?

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk,Image

from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def open():

    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File",filetypes=(("jpg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()

    my_btn = Button(root, text="Open files", command=open).pack()

#entry box

txt2 = Entry(root)

txt2.place(x=10, y=45)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I dont understand, you are calling the function in the button to call the same function again?

Answer (score -1):

**Did you mean get text in label and insert the text to an Entry?**
If yes, you can just make a `StringVar()` in the Entry
For example like this:

```
from tkinter import *         #For python 3                
from Tkinter import *         #For python 2             

root = Tk()         
txt = StringVar()            

#For inserting text
txt.set("This is a label and an entry")         
 
label = Label(root, textvariable=txt).pack()         

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=txt).pack()         

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the OP is using python 3.x or 2.x it will give error both ways, use `try` and `except`

Comment: This shows a poor programming practice. Both `label` and `entry` will be set to `None` so it's pointless to have those variables.